# How do I package a custom UWP templated control for reuse in other projects, and maybe for others to use?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

How do I package a custom UWP control for reuse in other projects, and maybe for others to use?

For example, I have a custom text editor that I would like to reuse without much hassle. So far I have just been putting all of my custom templated controls within my main project source code.

If I needed to reuse some control I would go through the tedious process of copying and pasting, etc., and i just feel like it is not the elegant/clean approach.

Remember that I need a UWP approach here. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I package a custom UWP control for reuse in other projects, and
>   maybe for others to use?

In this case, you can upload your custom templated controls to NuGet package. And then can install it in other projects or for others to use it. About how to create UI controls as NuGet packages, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/nuget/guides/create-ui-controls#add-toolboxassets-pane-support-for-xaml-controls).